# const arr = ["Barath", "Babu", "Prakash", "Praveen", "Arun"] output = {b: ["Barath", "Babu"], p:["Prakash", "Praveen"] , a:["Arun"]}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, xcode, encoding

How to get output using javascript ?????

const arr = ["Barath", "Babu", "Prakash", "Praveen", "Arun"]

output = {b: ["Barath", "Babu"], p:["Prakash", "Praveen"] , a:["Arun"]}

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your objective is. Do you want to sort the array into objects by first letter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array of strings by first letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71178336/group-array-of-strings-by-first-letter)

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77717366/8621208

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by iterating over the array and creating an object where the keys are the first letters of each name and the values are arrays containing names starting with that letter.

Here's how you can do this:

```js
const arr = ["Barath", "Babu", "Prakash", "Praveen", "Arun"];

const output = arr.reduce((result, name) => {
  const firstLetter = name[0].toLowerCase();
  result[firstLetter] = result[firstLetter] || [];
  result[firstLetter].push(name);
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

You can test this here, just copy paste code https://www.programiz.com/javascript/online-compiler/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intentions right, this should work:

```js
const arr = ["Barath", "Babu", "Prakash", "Praveen", "Arun"];
let output = {};
arr.forEach(element => {
  const letter = element.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  if (output[letter] === undefined) output[letter] = [];
  output[letter].push(element);
});

console.log(output);
```

We're using a function that is called for each element in your source array.
We then extract the first letter of each element, converting it to lowercase.
We check, whether the output object already has an element of that letter, if not, we generate one as an empty array.
Finally we push our element into this array which then exists for every first letter in the input array.

Note the bracket notation `object[prop]` to access object properties instead of the dot notation `object.prop`. This allows us to access properties dynamically without needing to know them beforehand.